# Why is a sweeping second hand required for IFR?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, time

The reasons why a clock is necessary for IFR [have been explained elsewhere](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9695/why-is-a-clock-necessary-for-ifr), but I haven't seen the reason that the clock has to have a sweeping second hand.

It seems like when timing things it would be more useful to have a ticking second hand, why is it expressly required that it be a sweep?

Comment: From what I can find, a "sweep-second hand" means that it is concentric with the hour and minute hands, not that it has to have a certain motion.

Comment: Odd language. Does it have bristles attached to it, like a little broom?

Comment: These days we don't worry about that because we can just pull out a phone to see what time it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @fooot mentions in the comments it means [that the hand must be concentric with the hour and minute hands](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sweep-second%20hand), it is not a reference between the difference of [deadbeat](http://wornandwound.com/horological-irony-dead-beat-seconds/) and [sweep seconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolex_Sweep) as many watch brands commonly reference now. This is a regulation that is intended to clarify the difference between a second hand that references the main dial and one that is on a sub dial. Historically planes may have [had more complicated nav clocks like this hamilton](http://www.hamiltonchronicles.com/2014/09/wwii-hamilton-h-37500-elapsed-time-clock.html) where the large second hand is for the chronometer and not the elapsed time clock.

[image]

([source](http://www.hamiltonchronicles.com/2014/09/wwii-hamilton-h-37500-elapsed-time-clock.html))

You can find what looks like one of the [early AC's on digital clocks here](http://www.cygnet-aero.com/AC/ac20-94.pdf). It references FAR 91.33 (which seems to no longer be in place) [you can find the original verbiage here](https://books.google.com/books?id=V5k5AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA150&lpg=PA150&dq=FAA%20FAR%2091.33%20sweep&source=bl&ots=rJL7apnYqj&sig=jy0PKdp7Npq8dhg8jrQ30ZI2NkQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVpZaOiqfUAhVE7IMKHa4nCdcQ6AEISzAG#v=onepage&q=FAA%20FAR%2091.33%20sweep&f=false). I can not find any FAA legal interpretation that further defines "sweeping seconds".

On a bit of a side note, [wrist watches (in any form) are not a legal substitute for a mounted clock](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/Interpretations/data/interps/2016/Nkugba%20-%20(2016)%20Legal%20Interpretation.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

In IFR flight you sometimes need to accurately time seconds for approaches or turns.

Early watches did not have a "seconds" hand. Some watches had a small secondary dial for seconds, but because of the small size it was hard to read. The rule was written "sweep-second hand" meaning a seconds hand that swept around the main dial so that a pilot could accurately time seconds.

As "fooot" says above, it does not refer to the type of motion the hand makes.

I have seen some aircraft equipped with digital clocks and often wondered if I needed to wear a "sweep-second hand" watch to be legal.

[Photo Source](https://www.quora.com/What-is-sweep-second-hand)

[image: Photo Source]

Comment: `I have seen some aircraft equipped with digital clocks and often wondered if I needed to wear a "sweep-second hand" watch to be legal.` Unless your watch is installed equipment on the aircraft, it still wouldn't matter. I believe (but don't know for sure) that would mean you add your watch to the aircraft's weight and balance data.

Comment: @SteveV. According to this [legal interpretation from the FAA, wrist watches are **not** a legal substitute for a mounted clock.](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/Interpretations/data/interps/2016/Nkugba%20-%20(2016)%20Legal%20Interpretation.pdf)

Comment: But digital presentations are legal even without a second hand.

Comment: Here is the ruling on using a watch (can't) but you can use an installed GPS or other Digital Clock. https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/Interpretations/data/interps/2016/Nkugba%20-%20(2016)%20Legal%20Interpretation.pdf `Another installed appliance with a permanent clock display that meets the requirements of § 91.205(d)(6) that displays "hours, minutes, and seconds with a sweep-second pointer or digital presentation," is adequate for the purposes ofthis regulation.`

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, local DPEs and the FAA FSDO agree that a digital clock with a seconds display may be used as an equivalent of an analog clock with a "sweep second" pointer.  This was a big deal, perhaps in the 80's, but everyone has come to accept the digital clock as acceptable for flight operations and flight tests.

The point about a clock aircraft mounted is a MEL / 91.213 issue that should be understood by wanna-be instrument pilots. Practically, installed GPS satisfies the clock requirement.