# Why is a clock required to be mounted on the instrument panel for IFR flights?

Tags: faa-regulations

A [clock](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/9695/why-is-a-clock-necessary-for-ifr) is required for IFR flights in the US but any clock doesn't do; the clock should be the [one mounted on the instrument panel](https://forums.jetcareers.com/threads/ifr-clock-requirement.89010/). What's the idea behind this requirement? Is it because random clocks the pilots might carry with them for their flights cannot be trusted?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The clock needs to be positioned such that you can see it easily as part of your instrument scan, and the sweep second hand needs to be there to make it easy to time intervals that are not whole minutes.

The regulation has been there for a long time, so the requirement should be considered in the light of how things used to be as well as what they are now.

A very practical example from 1969 follows. The regulation predates that by many years, I am sure, but the 1969 environment shows the need.

You're in a light single engine airplane (think Cessna 150 and later a Cessna 172). You're working on your instrument rating in actual conditions in the Pacific Northwest in a non-radar environment. You're in moderate turbulence and having to keep on eye on the icing. And, though it seems ridiculous now, we didn't use headsets but instead picked up a mic for each transmission, of which there were many because in the non-radar environment there were lots of reports.

You're inbound to the VOR on the airport, after which you'll proceed outbound to the NDB that is the final approach fix. Once at the NDB, you will fly 30 seconds farther outbound on the Rwy 16 ILS, which by the way since you have no HSI you're having to navigate by reverse sensing on the old VOR/ILS CDI with its swinging left/right needle. At the 30 second point, you're to turn right to the procedure turn outbound course and fly for 45 seconds (but maybe if that wind is from the east you should go for 60 seconds - better watch that CDI needle to see how fast you get full deflection).

Oh, damn, the instructor just covered up the directional gyro to simulate its failure. Now your only heading reference is the wet compass, which is bouncing around in the turbulence, and, besides, you can't remember whether it's going to precede or lag (and by how much) in the turn you have to make to reverse course for the inbound leg of the procedure turn. Ah, but wait, all you have have to do is fly a standard-rate turn for 60 seconds and you'll be in good shape.

So, thus far, we've had three separate needs to time things to seconds in a situation where we have our hands full - left hand on the yoke, right hand for throttle, carb heat, microphone.

Given all that, do you really want to have to keep pulling back the sleeve on your left arm to monitor a relatively small clock face? Much better to have a larger clock face right in front of you on the instrument panel.

Do we really need such a clock now? Perhaps not, but it doesn't hurt, and regulations are notoriously resistant to change.

And does anybody actually fly procedure turns anymore?

Comment: Upon reading this I have decided not to take flying lessons after all.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Take heart and go ahead, today's environment is far better, easier, safer. Electronic gyros which don't fail like the old spinning ones, autopilots common in training aircraft. HSIs (horizontal situation indicator) or glass cockpit displays that do away with having to think of reverse sensing. And when I tried to look up the outbound course of the procedure turn for the KEUG ILS Rwy 16, I found out they don't even show a procedure turn anymore. No longer necessary in the radar environment. Really, from this old fart's standpoint, they've taken all the fun out of it.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri You have no idea how many ADF's go inop on the day of an instrument check ride... This all sounds complicated and your instructor may have you do it once during training, but I've yet to year of an examiner pulling something so complicated. It is fun stuff to try when you have the instructor next to you, in real life you would ask for the nearest VFR airport and divert. Honestly if you took off in a 150/172 in icing/moderate turbulence I'd have to question your instructor's grasp on life.

Comment: When I was young, we had to do all @Terry describes, plus wiggle the mic plug to get the audio to come out right.  We also had to be careful where the charts were left, because in the rain everything leaked big time. At least back then much of the airspace I flew IFR in was uncontrolled, so we could just kick the tire, light the fire, and air file while tooling around in uncontrolled airspace.  The payphone at the airport, and the 300 yard dash to the airplane in the rain after a FSS clearance, was a real pain when operating in controlled airspace. There were few RCOs, and no cellphones.

Comment: @mongo And, as you allude to in your dash from the payphone to the airplane, you had to watch the clock because your clearance included a "void if not off by" time which was not that far in the future. A time that was necessary because they had to block off the controlled airspace you would be headed into until they either heard from you or the time expired.

Comment: So if we don't need a clock, under 91.205 now, where will the requirement be for a pilot to carry one?  From a regulatory standpoint, it is easier to have one in the aircraft, and to have it part of the MEL or some other requirement.

Comment: All these require a timer, not a clock.  Having spent many years with automotive clocks (which only got accurate when they got digital), all I can think of is "how do they absolutely guarantee the clock is  accurate, because a clock that is wrong is far more dangerous than no clock at all."  Today of course GPS answers that question, you ask the satellites.  Until they turn it off due to terrorist threat, and then you cannot fly at all.

Comment: @Harper You are correct that the aforementioned uses of the clock are all as a timer. However, there are instances where the time of day needs to be referenced. For example, the final part of holding instructions from ATC typically will be something like "expect further clearance at xx:xx" or "expect approach clearance at xx:xx." The time given will be the UTC time in 24 hour format, except that you may be given just "xx" which is to be interpreted as that number of minutes past the current hour.

Comment: Regs are hard to change because of familiarity.  When you get used to a clock being in a certain place, its utterly impossible to train yourself out of looking there.   I haven't worn a wristwatch for 25 years and recently caught myself looking at my wrist for the time.   If you doubt the power of habit, try moving, removing, or covering a clock that you use frequently at home or in the car.

Comment: Just happened to watch an episode of *Mayday* last night where the pilot flew into a mountain because he didn't check the stopwatch. Why he continued a circling approach in clouds is anybody's guess

Comment: I was looking around for some info on this instrument panel mounted 1960's era stopwatch clock.  I was confused because it had its own built in heater AND was vacuum sealed.  This explanation makes a lot of sense on why you need such a well built piece of equipment.

Answer (score 10):

We actually had a guy get busted for this.  No approved clock installed on the aircraft.

After that happened, we took out all the broken mechanical clocks on our aircraft, and installed digital clocks, with batteries and a 12V feed, and a 12V panel lighting wire.

Legally, you can have all the stopwatches and wristwatches you want, but for instrument flight, there must be a clock installed.  I have been told by an FAA Avionics Inspector that a GPS or other piece of avionics with a clock satisfies the requirement.  Back when we had LORAN-C, one of the units had a timer in it, and we did not have a clock on that aircraft. I cannot remember an aircraft GPS which does not have a clock feature.

Comment: I chuckle at a GPS without a clock, given my engineering background.  GPS figures out where you are by having clocks accurate to nanoseconds.  The idea of using these mighty impressive clocks in this way, then not presenting a clock to the user, is terribly amusing.

Comment: @CortAmmon Yeah, you know you have some seriously precise time measurements involved in your system when [you end up having to take _general relativity_ into account](http://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/~pogge/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html).

Comment: Agreed, the voting of multiple atomic clocks gives some pretty accurate time for determining MAP, or reporting an intersection. The real point of 91.205 is that it establishes the equipment requirements, not what the pilot must carry on board to supplement the equipment.

Comment: @reirab While you do have to take relativity into account, that article is false. GPS measures the difference between pulses from satellites, and relativity affects all the satellites similarily. So without relativity corrections, the pulses would come _slightly_ less often, and the satellite wouldn't be exactly at its calculated position. However, since _all_ signals come in at (almost) the same delay, the _difference_ is unchanged. So instead of the error being of the scale of light speed times relativity time shift, it is on the scale of satellite orbit velocity times relativity time shift.

Comment: (The pulses would come slightly _more_ often, but I was too late to correct it.)

Answer (score 6):

Among all clocks and watches it should be many models that are just unsuitable (cheap/unreliable, strange design, etc). There is a certain risk that clearly unsuitable model would formally match the requirements, or may appear it is doing. For instance, "digital presentation" - [binary ok](http://www.ledwatchstop.com/store/led-binary-c-5.html)?

If the watch is a part of the plane it probably has passed the certification so should be bearable.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point out that the FAA's answer says that the clock can be an **"installed appliance with a permanent clock display that meets the requirements of§ 91.205(d)(6) that displays "hours, minutes, and seconds with a sweep-second pointer or digital presentation," is adequate for the purposes of this regulation."** Please note that it points out that the clock display is permanent.  I interpret this as the GPS must have a clock visible on its screen no matter what page you are on.  In other words, if you have to change the GPS page to see the clock, it is not legal.  Some GPSs and PFDs display the clock constantly, no matter what page you're on.  These are legal.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the FAA’s official answer about clocks...
https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/practice_areas/regulations/Interpretations/data/interps/2016/Nkugba%20-%20%282016%29%20Legal%20Interpretation.pdf

Yes, your GPS clock is okay. If you have a garmin transponder like the Gtx 327, 330, etc. they have a great timer function...

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! We prefer answers to be 'self contained' rather than simply link to another source. If the link becomes invalid for some reason then the answer isn't useful any more. I suggest you add the most important point(s) from the FAA source in your answer. If you're new to the site, the [tour] may be helpful.

Comment: If there a way to directly upload the documents to the site? It succinctly answers the question bring asked, and is an official FAA ruling. That takes away the uncertainty of someone saying I read it on the internet...

Comment: No, the site doesn't support uploads (apart from images). The usual practice is to quote the most relevant part and link to the source. See [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/72462/62), for example.